# Como solucionar error CORS

Tags: php, html

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda con el siguiente problema.

Estoy utilizando la API de Adobe para visualizar PDF, pero a la hora de visualizar la pagina me da error de CORS como se ve en la imagen

Tengo lo siguiente a modo de ejemplo

```
<!--Get the samples from https://www.adobe.com/go/pdfembedapi_samples-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Adobe Document Services PDF Embed API Sample</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
 <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px">
 <div id="adobe-dc-view"></div>
 <script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
 <script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/2.10.3_1.10.0-1e3411b/ViewSDKInterface.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function()
    {
        var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<ID_CLIENTE>", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
        adobeDCView.previewFile(
       {
          content:   {location: {url: "https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea Brochure.pdf"}},
          metaData: {fileName: "Bodea Brochure.pdf"}
       });
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y tengo lo siguiente en el HTACCESS

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Header sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Pero resulta ser que me da este error en el navegador a pesar de poner dichas reglas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Y ahora... esa pagina donde esta el error de cors es tuya?

Comment: Siii la página es mía, es un página para hacer pruebas, pero no puedo quitar el error de cors

Comment: viewlicense.adobe.io es tuya????

Comment: No es la api de Adobe para visualizar PDF

Comment: y esa es la que protesta cors... sobre esa tenes que ver como hacer...

Comment: Por eso acudí acá para solicitar ayuda porque no puedo resolver el error

Comment: no estas entendiendo.. no esta en tu servidor esa api no? entonces deberias ir a ver su documentacion a ver si podes acceder a ella y como... Si la api es tuya, controlas cors... para apis que no son tuyas, no tenes control... o no te estoy entendiendo...